# jquery - can make text disappear but can't make hidden text visible

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, hide, show-hide

The link to hide text works, but the link to .show the hidden text doesn't show it and I don't see any errors.  See jsfiddle at: http://jsfiddle.net/tv6WQ/

```
<head>
<style type="text/css">   
    #shortandlong {color:red}   
    #thestory {visibility:hidden} 
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <span id="shortandlong">This is the short version but click </span><a href="#" id="showme">here...</a><span id="thestory"> now this is the full version</span><br/>
<span id="hideit">This text can be hidden </span>by clicking here <a href="#" id="hideme">here</a><br/>

</body>
```

js:

```
  $(document).ready(function () 
    { $('#hideme').click(function() 
      { $('#hideit').hide('fast');     
        return false;     } );    
      $("#showme").click(function() 
      { $('#thestory').show;     
        alert('Hello World');     
        return false;     } );    
    } );
```

Comment: show(). it's a function.

Comment: you are missing `()` next to show

Comment: You need to use `show();` instead `show;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things:

1. `show()` is a function so you need parentheses
2. `hide/show` change the `display` property, not the visibility - so change `$('#thestory').show` to `$('#thestory').css('visibility','visible')`

Answer (score 3):

.1.

```
$('#thestory').show()
```

not

```
$('#thestory').show
```

.2. Replace `visibility:hidden` with `display: none;` or change the visibility by `$('#thestory').css('visibility', 'visible');`

http://jsfiddle.net/pxStN/

Comment: agh you beat me while typing :)  I think everyone else just read bhamlin's comment lol, but didn't realize it's visibility that was the problem

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo, it should be `show()` in

```
 $("#showme").click(function() 
      { $('#thestory').show;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your aren't calling the method.  Add parenthesis after.  E.g. .show();